# Sending email with OAUTH2 and smtp.gmail (C#)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, smtp, google-oauth

I need to send a simple email, but using authentication. **Using AppPasswords is not an option.**

My difficulty is to retrieve the response after sending the authorization and at what point should I generate the email. I know that to send the email I must use the password and authentication user identity.

Here's what I've done.

## Credentials are read from a file

```
ClientSecrets varClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets();
 
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
       new FileStream(pathFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read))
{
    varClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets;
    
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        varClientSecrets,
        new[] { "email", "profile", "https://mail.google.com/" },
        "use",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)                        
        ).Result;

    strCLIENT_ID = varClientSecrets.ClientId;
    strCLIENT_SECRET = varClientSecrets.ClientSecret;
}

// Create Gmail API service.
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "XXX"
});
```

## Get credential data

```
   // Define parameters of request.
UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");



ConsultaWeb CW = new ConsultaWeb();
IRestResponse irrRetornoServidor = null;

strSCOPE = credential.Token.Scope;
 
strREDIRECT_URI = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";

strTokenURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"; 

/// model: {Authorization: token_type base64(userEmail:userPassword)}

strHeader = "Authorization: " + credential.Token.TokenType + " " 
    + Base64.EncodeToBase64(userEmail + ":" + userPassword);


strURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
   + "?scope=" + strSCOPE
   + "&access_type=offline"
   + "&include_granted_scopes=true"
   + "&response_type=code"
   + "&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value"
   + "&redirect_uri=" + strREDIRECT_URI
   + "&client_id=" + strCLIENT_ID;
   
strServidorRetorno = CW.RequisicaoWebREST(strURL, GET, JSON
    , out irrRetornoServidor, "", "", "", "", strHeader);

// Return from OAuth 2.0 server
// OAuth 2.0 server responds to your application's access request
// using the URL specified in the request.

////If the user approves the access request, the response
//will contain an authorization code. If the user does not approve the request,
//the response will contain an error message.

//The authorization code or error message that is returned to the web server
//appears on the query string, as shown below:

strAuthCode = "";
```

## Get response from server

```
if ((short)irrRetornoServidor.StatusCode == (short)RegrasGlobais.HTTPStatusCode.OK)
{
    if (irrRetornoServidor.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("error"))
    {
        // An error response: 
        // https://oauth2.example.com/auth?error=access_denied
        return -1;
    }
    else if (irrRetornoServidor.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("ServiceLogin"))
    {
        //An authorization code response
        // https://oauth2.example.com/auth?code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7
        // strAuthCode = "P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7";
        // how to get the autorization response, if this open in  the browser
        strAuthCode = irrRetornoServidor.ResponseUri.Query.ToString();
        
    }

}
else
{
    return -1;
}
```

## send the email

```
// Gmail API server address
    //MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    // build mail
```

## thks

my problem was and how to do the authentication before sending the email. Now I got it. Thanks.

Comment: You have to adhere to the GMAIL Server requirements  GMAIL does not use OAUTH and GMAIL requires you to use CREDENTIALS.  I think you want a two port application. 1) a client to a server with OAUTH 2) Server to SMTP Email (GMAIL).  You want to take the clients credentials and use at server to send an email.  So server needs both OAUTH and Authentication.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im a little confused as to what it is you are trying to do. You say you want to send an email using the SMTP server yet you are connecting to the gmail api.  Why not just send your emails via the gmail api then?

Assuming you have just gone in the wrong direction. You should know that the SmtpClient can handle the client from the google .Net client library directly. Just let it get its access token when needed.

```
await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2, CancellationToken.None);
```

If all you want to do is send an email from the smtp server. Try the following sample.

## Full sample

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;

var to = "test@Gmail.com";
var from = "test@gmail.com";

var path = @"C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json";
var scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" };


var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(path).Secrets,
    scopes,
    "GmalSmtpUser",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), true)).Result;



var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    From = from,
    To = to,
    MessageText = "This is a test message using https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol",
    Subject = "Testing GmailSMTP with XOauth2"
};

try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        
        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (message.From, credential.Token.AccessToken);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2, CancellationToken.None);
        
        client.Send(message.GetMessage());
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


public class EmailMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }

    public MimeMessage GetMessage()
    {
        var body = MessageText;
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("From a user", From));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("To a user", To));
        message.Subject = Subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };
        return message;
    }
}
```